# How would I implement procedurally generated tiles in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, tiles, procedural-generation, tilemap

I'm creating a simple top down Zelda-esque game in libgdx, and I want to implement tile-based dungeons that are procedurally generated, similar to [***this.***](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-procedurally-generated-dungeon-cave-system--gamedev-10099)

Libgdx does have a class called TiledMap which would seem to fit my needs, however documentation outside of the official docs suggests that TiledMaps can only be used in conjunction with .tmx files, or in other words pre-designed maps. 
I've done a fair amount of Googling to no avail, so I'm asking here as a last resort hoping that someone has experience using libgdx for dynamically-generated tile maps.

edit: Could I use [***StaticTiledMapTiles***](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/tiled/tiles/StaticTiledMapTile.html) in conjunction with the tutorial I linked to above to achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you write the data of the generated maps to a .tmx file and use that in LibGdx?

Comment: That's interesting. I suppose I could, although I feel like that wouldn't be ideal for quick generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on advice from [/r/gamedev](http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev), I've decided to forgo the use of libgdx's TiledMap, etc. built-in classes and just build my own.

I can go into greater detail if requested, but here's what I've done, essentially.

1: Generate a dungeon using the algorithm I originally linked to, and store tile coordinates (not pixel coords) using a `Coordinate` class I made in a `HashMap<Coord, MapTile>`. `MapTile` is just a class that has data about the type of tile.

2: In the `draw()` function of my main class I added the following code

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Coord, MapTile> dungeonMap = dungeonGen.getMap();
        for(Entry<Coord, MapTile> entry : dungeonMap.entrySet()){
            Coord coord = entry.getKey();
            MapTile tile = entry.getValue();

            if((inCameraFrustum(coord.getX() * tileSize, coord.getY() * tileSize, 100))){
                game.batch.draw(dungeonGen.getTileTexture(tile),
                        coord.getX() * tileSize, coord.getY() * tileSize);
            }

        }
```

Which iterates over every `Coordinate` in the `dungeonMap` and draws the tile (if the coordinate is in the camera frustum) with a global `tileSize` offset.

Answer (score 9):

You can create tiled maps on without using .tmx.

```
TiledMap map = new TileMap();
MapLayers layers = map.getLayers();

TiledMapTileLayer layer1 = new TiledMapTileLayer(width, height, tile_width, tile_height);
Cell cell = new Cell();

cell.setTile(new StaticTiledMapTile(texture_region));
layer1.setCell(x, y, cell);

layers.addLayer(layer1);

Each of these classes are in the docs for libgdx.
```

Comment: This give me an idea. Up on researching, I found these example code to dynamically generate tilemap without a need of `.tmx` file from libgdx https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/bench/TiledMapBench.java#L64-L84. Thanks.